# Как запустить batch file

Tags: c++, qt

Есть у нас batch file, и в нем:

```
mkdir test
dir
```

Как можно запустить этот файл?

Comment: `system("имя_файла.bat")`

Comment: @Harry не получается

Comment: `system("cmd /c имя_файла.bat")`

Comment: @AnT Это лишнее, `system` автоматом вызывает командный интерпретатор. Конечно, получающееся `cmd /c cmd /c ttt.bat` тоже сработает, но это уже лишнее.

Comment: можно ли без система вызвать?

Comment: Да сформулируйте же наконец внятно вопрос! Как запустить - вам написали. Теперь без `system`... Зачем? Чего вы добиваетесь? Не написали ТЗ - получите в ответ ХЗ...

Comment: Иметь под рукой всю мощь такого языка как c++ и использовать её лишь для запуска батника с mkdir - это почище, чем микроскопом колоть орехи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    LPSTR cmdLine = (LPSTR)"C:\\rrr.bat";

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        printf_s("Создан процесс!\n");
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    else
        printf_s("Ошибка создания процесса! %d", GetLastError());

    system("pause");
}
```

если хочешь, что бы не создавалось новое окно, замени CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE на 0

использовать system для создания процесса - плохая практика

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/ProcThread/creating-processes

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, у меня ошибка:        C:\fakepath\mainwindow.cpp:118: ошибка: cannot convert 'LPSTR {aka char*}' to 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'WINBOOL CreateProcessW(LPCWSTR, LPWSTR, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, WINBOOL, DWORD, LPVOID, LPCWSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOW, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)'
         if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
                                                                                                     ^

Comment: LPWSTR cmdLine = (LPWSTR)L"C:\\rrr.bat";

Answer (score 2):

Вот это

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    system("echo mkdir test > rrr.bat");
    system("echo dir >> rrr.bat");
    system("rrr.bat");
}
```

компилируется Visual C++ без замечаний, создает `rrr.bat` с вашим содержимым, вызывает его...

```
G:\Tmp\Test>test.exe

G:\Tmp\Test>mkdir test

G:\Tmp\Test>dir
 Том в устройстве G имеет метку Data
 Серийный номер тома: 40D0-D63A

 Содержимое папки G:\Tmp\Test

10.10.2018  09:24    <DIR>          .
10.10.2018  09:24    <DIR>          ..
10.10.2018  09:24                19 rrr.bat
10.10.2018  09:24    <DIR>          test
10.10.2018  09:24               163 test.cpp
10.10.2018  09:24           112 640 test.exe
               3 файлов        112 822 байт
               3 папок  97 676 894 208 байт свободно
```

Почему не получается у вас - посмотрите внимательно, все ли вы делаете верно...

Comment: В Qt не получается!

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Конкретно? Каким вы видите это "получается"?

Comment: "Не получается",- означает, что черный экран выходит, а действий никаких нету

Comment: Попробуйте написать `dir > dir` и проверьте, создался ли файл `dir`. Или добавить `pause`.